# Flutter Slider Not updating (NOT moving after being dragged)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, slider

## Dart Code `sliders_view.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class Element {
  Element(this.rawName);

  final String rawName;
  double _rating = 40;

  // getters
  double get rating => _rating;
  // setters
  set rating(double value) {
    _rating = value;
    print('Changed: ' + value.toString());
  }
}

class SlidersView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SlidersViewState createState() => _SlidersViewState();
}

class _SlidersViewState extends State<SlidersView> {
  final DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot>(
            future: dbRef
                .child('foo_bar')
                .once(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<Element> elements = [];
                for (var element in snapshot.data.value) {
                  elements.add(Element(element['name']));
                }
                return Column(children: [
                  for (Element element in elements)
                    CupertinoSlider(
                        value: element.rating,
                        activeColor: Colors.grey,
                        max: 100,
                        onChanged: (newRating) {
                          setState(() {
                            element.rating = newRating;
                          });
                        })
                ]);
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

Before I switched to a `FutureBuilder` to use FireBase I had a hardcoded list of `Element` objects and this worked fine, so I'm sure it has something to do with the future builder.

### OUTPUT (from dragging on the sliders):

```
Reloaded 5 of 848 libraries in 150ms.
flutter: Changed: 40.37878787878788
flutter: Changed: 43.40909090909091
flutter: Changed: 45.3030303030303
flutter: Changed: 48.33333333333333
flutter: Changed: 50.22727272727272
flutter: Changed: 51.36363636363635
flutter: Changed: 52.49999999999999
```

[image]

## VIDEO:

https://www.loom.com/share/733177569de94bc8905cf1f3d81e6f59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that new `Element` objects are being created every time `build` is called, essentially losing the new data that you set in the previous `build`.

So to solve this, you need to store your `elements` list outside of the `FutureBuilder`. It should be stored outside of the `build` method completely. Instead of just adding data to this list, you should compare your current list with the one in `snapshot` and essentially pull them even, removing elements that no longer exist, adding new ones, but not touching elements that are in both. Then the rest of your code should work with no problem. This *might* result in some jank, especially if the lists get too big, but testing is the only way to know for sure.

Alternatively, you could just do away with the `FutureBuilder` in this case and extract all of the list processing code to `initState`. Call `dbRef.child('foo_bar').once()` in `initState` and with a `.then` callback, fill your elements list and call `setState`.